# Read data from file in every ticks

Tags: file, netlogo

I am using NetLogo and I want to read two types of data (for example "x" and "y") from a file for each agent in each time step (tick). Does anyone know how I can do this?

Here is the code:

```
breed [agents agent]
agents-own [  need  tax]

to setup
  clear-all
  define-xy
  reset-ticks
end

to define-xy
  file-open "D:\\data\\xy.txt"
   while [not file-at-end?]
   [
  let items read-from-string (word "[" file-read-line "]")
   crt 1 [
     set xcor item 0 items  
     set ycor item 1 items
     set label ycor
   ]
  ]
  file-close
end

to go
  tick
  if (ticks = 5)
  [
    stop
    ]
end
```

Now if I want to define two parameters that are tax and need that change each tick what should I do. I am a little bit confused.In the code above I can do a one time read from a file that has two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. You give too little information about how the data is going to be structured in the text file, so I will suppose that you have only two columns. So the text file looks like this:

```
1 3
4 5
9 11
-1 33
```

First, I think you'll need a way to control the agents, I'm again supposing you create a determinated number of agents and that row 1 of text file is used for agent 1.

That said, next thing you want to do is to use `repeat number-of-agents [tasks]`

And `tasks` could look something like:

```
let auxiliar 0
repeat number-of-agents [
let data-read read-file-line
ask agent auxiliar [ set var1 first data-read 
                     set var2 last data-read ]
tick ;Reads, Assigns, Ticks and all over again.
set auxiliar auxiliar + 1
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. but I still have problem: It seems that auxiliar is the agent's number. do I need to define it in advance? If yes, how? Also I want to change these sets of parameters for each agent in each tick. where should I put your answer? in setup or go?thanks

Comment: Auxiliar is not agent's number. You need to know `number-of-agents` before reading the file. This can be done by either using a lever or by reading the same file but with a new value that'd mean `number-of-agents`. `auxiliar`, in the other hand, is a value started in 0.

Comment: I have four agents and I want to update two parameters (for example x and y) for each agent in each tick. I have all the data in one file. I want to run the model for 5 ticks. So as I have 4 agents and 5 ticks I have a file with two columns and 20 rows and I want to read 4 lines in each tick.

Comment: Well then it's only a matter of playing with the code I give you above. It's pretty much the same, only the order of actions and number of repetitions change. We'd love to see some code.