# read from a specific file in each tick in NetLogo

Tags: file, netlogo

I am using NetLogo. I have 10 agents and I want to **change** one of the attributes of my agents in each tick. I have a .txt file and I want to read ten lines of the file in each tick. In other words, I want to read 10 lines in the first tick and then in the next tick read another ten lines. So I want to **keep the file open** and read 10 lines of it in each tick. Do you know how I can manage it?
I tried to do it but still I have problem. Here is part of the code:

```
to go
  tick
  define-globals
  if (ticks = 10)
  [stop
    file-close]
end
```

anf for define globals:

```
to define-globals
  file-open "D:\\data\\percentage.txt"
      let per file-read
       set percentage per
           ask agents [ set label percentage ]
end
```

the problem is when I want to run the model for the second or third etc. time, I recive this message:
**The end of file has been reached**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Netlogo-Read data from file in every ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482889/netlogo-read-data-from-file-in-every-ticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should let your agents read from your file.

```
file-open "myfile.txt"
ask agents [set label file-read]
```

As long as your don't explicitly close the file, opening it again just returns you to the same place in the file

Comment: So, where should I close the file if I want to keep it open for the all ticks?